# Custom Keras loss function that conditionally creates a zero gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

My problem is I don't want the weights to be adjusted if `y_true` takes certain values. I do not want to simply remove those examples from training data because of the nature of the RNN I am trying to use.

Is there a way to write a conditional loss function in Keras with this behavior?

For example: if `y_true` is negative then apply zero gradient so that parameters in the model do not change, if `y_true` is positive `loss = losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)`.

Comment: Include another input variable `mask` which is zero for the specific values of `y_true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom loss function and simply use `K.switch` to conditionally get zero loss:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras import losses

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
    return K.switch(K.flatten(K.equal(y_true, 0.)), K.zeros_like(loss), loss)
```

Test:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))

model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam')

weights, bias = model.layers[0].get_weights()

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0])

model.train_on_batch(x, y)

# check if the parameters has not changed after training on the batch
>>> (weights == model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]).all()
True

>>> (bias == model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]).all()
True
```

Comment: I'm not sure how Keras calculates gradients, does zero loss automatically mean zero gradient?

Comment: @NickMerrill Well, the gradient of a constant, including zero, with respect to any variable is zero, right?

Comment: Of course, it's just kind of a black box to me how keras performs this calculation. Is there a simply way to "see" the gradient or to check and weight or bias to see if it is changing?

Comment: @NickMerrill Sure, wait a few minutes. I am writing an update.

Comment: @NickMerrill I have updated my answer and added a test as well as some minor updates to the `custom_loss` function.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response and test code!! That works on my end and is very straightforward. I learned a lot. For anyone else testing you will need to import losses and layers from keras to run the Test code.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `y`'s are in batches, you need to select those from the batch which are non-zero in the custom loss function

```
def myloss(y_true, y_pred):
    idx  = tf.not_equal(y_true, 0)
    y_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, idx)
    y_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, idx)
    return losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

Then it can be used as such:

```
model = keras.Sequential([Dense(32, input_shape=(2,)), Dense(1)])
model.compile('adam', loss=myloss)

x = np.random.randn(2, 2)
y = np.array([1, 0])
model.fit(x, y)
```

But you might need extra logic in the loss function in case all `y_true` in the batch were zero, in this case, the `loss` function can be modified as such:

```
def myloss2(y_true, y_pred):
    idx  = tf.not_equal(y_true, 0)
    y_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, idx)
    y_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, idx)
    loss = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.shape(y_pred)[0], 0), lambda: tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32), lambda: losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
    return loss
```